# Windows won't open .py files, even when "python launcher for windows (console)" is assigned

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, path, python-3.5

Phyton was working fine, until one day IDLE refused to open (nothing happened when I double clicked it), so I decided to reinstall it. After I was done (I installed Python 3.5), IDLE was working again, however all of my scripts had blank icons instead of a Python icon (even though Windows was set to open it with "python launcher for windows (console)"). I tried to open thouse but they would instead open in command line and close after a fraction of a second (which is strange, since some of those scripts were supposed to create applications that should stay put until the "x" (close) button is pressed).
I tried to delete python in path variables and then add it back again, but it didn't work. I also tried to assign other python executables (like "python.exe" and "pythonw") to open those files, whithout success...

Comment: First thing I would do is double check your environmental variables.  Python 3.5.0 made some really wonky decisions as to installation, breaking with tradition not only in location but also naming convention (instead of default to Python35, it defaults to Program Files/Python 3.5... and that's only if you explicitly tell it to install for all users).  I returned to 3.4.3 myself, but if you insist on 3.5.0 then try reinstalling and letting the installer add to path.

Comment: The icon problem will be fixed in 3.5.1. Change the file association back to the launcher, but note that it defaults to running Python 2 if that's installed. Scripts that require Python 3 should start with a virtual shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/python3` or just `#!python3`.